# How do I add JavaScript to an ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a simple View and I wish to add a [JQuery DatePicker JavaScript](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) to this view (and not *every* view, via a masterpage).

I'm not sure what is the best way to do this.

Second, I'm conscious of where/when my JavaScript loads. I'm a fan of YSlow and it recommends that I add any scripts to the bottom of the page, which I do.

So, how could I do both?

Here's the view:

```asp
<%@ Page
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <p>
        <label for="StartDate">Start Date:</label>
        <!-- JQuery DatePicker to be added, here. -->
    </p>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way is put a content placeholder at the bottom of your master page, then the specific slave page that needs the javascript can specify the placeholders contents as the required javascript. Other pages that don't need the javascript simply don't specify any content for the placeholder.

Comment: Cheers :) For the record, i've added a new ContentPlaceHolder at the bottom of the page, right above the </body> tag. Discussion about that, here: http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_5.html

Comment: Agreed, will usually have one in the head as well.. the project i'm working on noe is very JS heavy, so jquery & jquery ui are loaded via master... The client browser gets this at login, and can cache it...

Answer (score 22):

In ASP.NET MVC3, you can now use a RenderSection to achieve this, at least for simpler scenarios. Just add a RenderSection to the bottom of the layout page, and from your view fill in the appliation code

RenderSections: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=636

Comment: +1 for the RenderSections link. That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Your MasterPage should have a ContentPlaceHolder for the head.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Then you're able to include head elements (JavaScripts, StyleSheets, etc...) in your views:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery/ui/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="/Styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: this answer was better, except that it was putting it in the head .. when i did say it should be added to the bottom of the page. So winob0t gets the tick.